# Api not working in ajax call but working fine in post man

Tags: ajax, postman

I am using a web api in my postman and it working fine in postman and i am getting proper response the but when i am using it for ajax call then getting "405 method not allowed". Please help me resolve it. Thanks

Below is my postman parameters :-

> url:"https://services-sit.wba.com/services/gbl/customers/v1/searchAddress?UUID=ea8034fe-7c81-11e9-8f9e-2a86e4085a59&Text=wr53da&IsMiddleware=True&Origin=GBR&Countries=UnitedKingdom&Limit=2&Language=ENG"
>
> headers : x-api-key : 'zyx'
>
> method : 'get'

=====================================================

Below is how i am using postman call to ajax call

```
$.ajax({type:'GET',
               //data:{id:'aaaaa'},
           crossDomain: true,
               url:"https://services-sit.wba.com/services/gbl/customers/v1/searchAddress?UUID=ea8034fe-7c81-11e9-8f9e-2a86e4085a59&Text=wr5 3da&IsMiddleware=True&Origin=GBR&Countries=United Kingdom&Limit=2&Language=ENG",
           headers: { 'x-api-key': 'xyz', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               beforeSend: function(xhrObj){},
        success:function(data){
                            $(".loader").fadeOut('slow');
                        //var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);}
});
```

Comment: Can you check without passing the 'Content-Type' header in the ajax call. Looks like you were not sending any headers in the Postman call.

Comment: yes i have done the but still not working!

Comment: I think you are doing a CORS request which could be causing this issue.